# Frequency of refrigeration cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

How often does the refrigeration cycle repeat itself? I have read that the compressor runs at about 1000 rpm. Does that mean that the frequency of the cycle is 1000/60=17 Hz?

Comment: Aren't most refrigerant systems continuous operations?

Comment: @ChetMiller, there is a thermostat inside refrigerators that holds a specified temperature within a narrow range.  The refrigerators have to cycle on and off to do this.

Comment: nilos, could you be more specific?  A refrigeration "cycle" may mean one complete trip around a refrigeration circuit for a refrigerant molecule.  You are implying that you want to know something about how fast the compressor is repeating its cycle as it is producing high pressure refrigerant.

Comment: @DavidWhite That is not what I was referring to.  That thermostat cycling is obviously very low frequency. But during the on-operation, the refrigeration circuit at any time can be regarded as continuous and steady state (i.e., not involving a piston compressor), right?

Comment: Yes, during operation, the refrigeration cycle very quickly gets to a steady state, and stays at steady state while it is running.

Comment: @DavidWhite, I thought that the period of the refrigeration cycle was the period of the oscillating force the compressor exerted to the refrigerant. But now I see that this is wrong...

Answer (score 0):

No, that just means that the compressor delivers a given amount of refrigerant 1000 times a minute assuming a simple piston type compressor.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the mass of refrigerant and the thermodynamic cycle, you can find the amount of heat transferred as all the refrigerant goes around one cycle.

Compare that with rate of cooling the device produces, and you know how long each cycle takes.

Answer (score 0):

The rpm of a compressor tells you nothing without knowing the horse power, etc. Large compressors can move a lot of refrigeration at low rpms, while a smaller compressor may have high rpms but still not move very much. Also the frequency of the cycle will depend on the total volume that the systems needs to fill. This is determined by the supply and return pipes diameter and lengths, as well as the capacity of the equipment indoor and outdoor. You need to know all these variables to determine how often the refrigerate cycles through the system.

Answer (score 0):

No, the refrigerant piping coupled with the compressibility of the refrigerant gas means that the *pulsate flow* from the compressor gets smoothed out into a *continuous flow*. That continuous flow persists throughout the system, meaning that the overall thermodynamic cycle is *continuous*.

The thermostat then *duty-cycles* the compressor on and off for minutes at a time to maintain the temperature inside the refrigerator within its upper and lower control limits.